# Need a bash for loop command

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, ssh

I have these 40 servers that I need to test this command:

```
ssh -qt user@server1X 'hostname'
```

I have server1X up to server40X here and I don't want to manually repeat all the commands, can you share me any loop command to use for linux box? like for i.. or while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 40`;
do
    ssh -qt user@server${i}X 'hostname'
done
```

Comment: `server$iX` will try and fail to expand a variable named `$iX`. It needs to be `server${i}X`.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I made some shortcuts on your suggested script


`#!/bin/bash
svr=server
for i in {1..40}
do
    ssh -qt user@svr$i"X" 'hostname'
done`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for i in {1..40}:; do ssh -qt user@server${i}X 'hostname'; done
```

Comment: `server$iX` will try and fail to expand a variable named `$iX`. It needs to be `server${i}X`.

Comment: @Keith I just realized it.. Thanks! Fixed it